# Why didn't detective Boney question Amy's neighbor for details?

Tags: plot-explanation, gone-girl

In Gone Girl, Amy's neighbor Noelle Hawthorne comes to detective Boney and tells her that she was a friend of Amy. Next we see that while her investigation is going on, Noelle comes to Amy & Nick's house, but when the detective sees her at the door, she asks policemen to escort her out.

It was a complex case and detective was desperately looking for some solid information. Why didn't she question Amy's neighbor and friend? It is pretty evident that the neighbor hadn't told everything to the detective, because she shows up at the gathering and publicly discloses that Amy was pregnant. At this the detective seems shocked, but earlier when that lady was coming to her, she avoided her.

Why didn't the detective question her in detail, the first time?

Comment: Though, they definitely interrogated her, since I think it was her who told the police that things in their marriage weren't too well. And I'd surmise this interrogation was as soon as possible and thus before she went to Nick's house. But why she didn't tell the police about the pregnancy I don't know either (if that was the case at all). Or she might have interrogated her later, but at Nick's house wasn't a particularly good place and time to do a proper interrogation, the neighbor was just messing up the scene at this point, so she needed to be escorted away.

Comment: why don't you convert this into an answer ?

Comment: I'm not too sure of it either, it's all just speculation based on common sense. I'd still like to watch the movie again to write a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two possible reasons for this.

Firstly, whilst in the movie **Noelle Hawthorne** appears on the very first day of the hunt for Amy, in the books she isn't introduced until later at the search party headquarters. Therefore, there were no set lines for her in the "early days" of the investigation coming from the book. It's plausible that the film makers didn't want to include any and instead simply wanted to give **Casey Wilson** (the actress) more screen time, as she was funny, completely over the top and entertaining.

Secondly, and perhaps a more likely possibility, is that there was evidence in the flat of a struggle. Initially at least, Nick is not the suspect. Whilst the information she had was of vital importance, there were more pressing concerns in the immediate aftermath of her disappearance. The entire house needed to be cordoned off, the scene needed to be analysed, blood traces needed to be collected - in other words, *objective* evidence took priority over interviewing a slightly hysterical woman.

As time progressed and more and more evidence seemed to implicate Nick, suddenly the *subjective* views of those around him became far more important to the investigation.